# Free Visual Studio Pluggin For Code COmpletion in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++

I am doing some C++  projects in visual c++ using Visual Studio Pro 2010. But unfortunately, auto complete support, automatic brace completion are not there. For example, If you type "in", there is not auto completion pop up windows showing that "Int", if u type "ret", nothing is shown for "return", these simple auto completion feature are available in netbeans, eclipse. But not in VS.

I used Visual assist x for a month but it is not a free extension. Can someone help???? is there any free pluggin that can do these things in C++...

There are also good pluggin that serves these issues like resharper. But all these works for C# and VB

Answer (score 0):

Auto completion should be available trough Visual Studio directly. As for extra options this may not do all that you're used to with Visual Assist X, but it's free and it helps you make some changes to the code very easily: [DevExpress Refactor! for C++](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/RefactorCPP/)